# Plotting Bessel function with two variables and with limits

Tags: plotting, special-functions

I am working on a physics problem where I am trying to plot a fraction consisting of a Bessel function and its derivative. They are a function of two variables `m` and `V`, which stand for the mass and the volume. I am trying to plot under the limits where `m -> 0` and `V -> ∞`. My supervisor told me that a wierd thing happens, because the two limits do not commute, so the order of which limit you take first matters!

I have tried working with the Limit function, but I can not seem to get all the variables and limits into the plot at once — even though I get the correct form of my graph.

If I try one variable:

```
Plot[{1, (BesselI[1, v]/BesselI[0, v])}, {v, -10, 10}]
```

I of course don't incorporate the limits, but if I try to write

```
F1 := Plot[Limit[(BesselI[1, m]/BesselI[0, m]), m -> 0]]
F2 := Plot[Limit[(BesselI[1, v]/BesselI[0, v]), v -> Infinity]]
Show[{1, F1, F2}]
```

the code does not work and I get the error

> $RecursionLimit::reclim: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded. >>

and

> `Hold[Limit[m, m -> 0]]`.

I am very new to Mathematica, and trying to learn. I have of course searched a lot before asking, but could not seem to find anything that worked.

**Summary:**

I am trying to plot the two bessel functions, which are functions of the variables m and V:

$$\frac{I_{1}(mV)}{I_{0}(mV)} \quad {\rm with}\ m \rightarrow 0\ {\rm and}\ v\rightarrow \infty$$

Not that it is of great importance, but we of course have that the derivative of the zeroth order gives the first order:

$$I_{0}'(z)=I_{1}(z)$$

Comment: `infinity` should be `Infinity` (capitalization matters!), and your `Show` does not make sense; you should get a warning and return the input: `Show[{1, 0, 1}]`.

Comment: There's no reason for a recursion error, I suspect clearing the kernel resolves that specific issue. It isn't clear what you're trying to do, there's no reason why you would need `Limit[]` to plot these.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, i did not see that, thank you. I noticed that i of couse do not plot anyting, so i have updated my original answer so that it actually makes sense what i am trying to do. Still it gives me one of two errors: "Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded" or "Could not combine the graphics objects in Show" the former error comes if i dont put a plotting range for m and V, and the latter if i do. I have looked at this for way to long, maybe i am blind to something crucial missing?

Comment: Thank you guys for such fast responses - i appreciate it a lot! Well you are right Feyre that i do not _need_ the limits, but i am trying to look at the function in these limits. My Bessel functions are solutions to a group integral i performed and i want to see how my result behaves in these limits.

Comment: `F1` and `F2` are just numbers so you won't `Plot` them. `Show` is for combining, let's say, plots - see the docs. If you want to look at the asymptotic behaviour of the functions, you should check `Series`. And you're not telling us everything, because the codes don't lead to a recursion error.

Comment: In the updated `F1` and `F2` you use `Plot` incorrectly. Again, the limits are just numbers, but, like in the first code, you need a range to plot in. Basically, your codes are `Plot[1]` and `Plot[0]`, which don't make sense. Please go through the documentation of the functions you're using to be sure you know how to use them.

Comment: Even though i have looked at the documentation before i now see that i made on big mistake, my Bessel functions should of course range over the m*V variables values. I now have    Plot[BesselI[1, m*v]/BesselI[0, m*v], {m, 0, 100}] but i get an empty plot, if i try to add a range for v i get the error ""Options expected (instead of {v,0,100}) beyond position 2 in Plot"" and "An option must be a rule or a list of rules.". I feel that i have a better starting point for my expression, but i still do not see how to incorporate the limits.

Comment: `Plot` is for 1D functions. If you have a 2D one, see `Plot3D[BesselI[1, m v]/BesselI[0, m*v], {m, 0, 100}, {v, 0, 100}]`. I suggest you go thoroughly through some tutorials first, e.g. https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/

Comment: I definitely have a 1d funtion, so my code above is apparently not right notation. I can see from the plot that you wrote that i get the right form, but in 2D instead of one. If i write      Plot[BesselI[1, m]/BesselI[0, m], {m, 0, 10}] i get everything right, but again without incorporating any limits, and now with only dependancy on m and not V. My Bessel functions should depend on a factor, let us call it k=m*V but then it does not make sense to let m and V go towards different limits.